# How to filter resources in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently, I'm building a blog in Rails and I am being curious is there a right way to display resources in the following manner?

[image]

In this case you may be able to list all the posts, and if needed, separate category posts.

You'd normally say - use scopes, however I'm not sure scopes are gonna produce the following adressess: **/blog/features**, **/blog/releases**.

So, how can I do this?

Comment: I suggest you try this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#connecting-urls-to-code   And instead of `id` use a different name for the param. Then in the controller action check for that param value and use scoping

Comment: @Kkulikovskis I almost got your idea. Couldn't you provide an example of how it potentially might look?

Answer (score 2):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :blogs, path: "blog" do 
   get ":category", to: :index, on: :collection #-> url.com/blog/:category
end

#app/controllers/blogs_controller.rb
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
   def index
       @posts = params[:category] ? Post.joins(:category).where(category: {name: params[:category]}) : Post.all
   end
end

#app/views/posts/index.html.erb
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
   ...
<% end %>
```